# How to typecast Sender?

Tags: .net, casting, click, delphi-prism, sender

I have a ToolStripButton as a sender within a click event. I need to be able to typecast the sender as a Toolstripbutton and retrieve its tag property as an integer. I think, I am doing that in the following code. My program compiles successfully, but it raises invalid typecast run-time error.

```
theTool := TMakerTool((sender as ToolStripButton).tag);

TMakerTool = public enum

theTool:TMakerTool
```

I see that the tag property is an object that contains the tag as a string.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that sender really is `ToolStripButton`?

Comment: Yes, it is suppose to be ToolStripButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to follow Dr. Wily's Apprentice's answer, but it didn't work. However, he did help me understand it better.

If anyone interested, I was able to get the error to go away by doing the following.

```
theTool := TMakerTool(int32.Parse((sender as ToolStripButton).tag.ToString));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [an `Enum` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) that provides [a Parse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx) (also [a TryParse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) as of v4).

Although I'm not familiar with Delphi, I think that you can do the following:

```
TMakerTool(Enum.Parse(typeof(TMakerTool), (sender as ToolStripButton).tag.ToString(), true));
```

Reference Link:
http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/convert-string-to-enum-using-delphi-prism/

Comment: I made the changes and it is asking me to instantiate TMakertool as an object

Comment: It is treating TMakerTool as a class. Why?